# What is the cause of "database table definition wrong" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

This is my first step to programming.guys your help hands required.I watched youtube video & write small program,the exact way he written..he doesn't have error.but i got the error.I just passed the textbox values database.(error is database table definition wrong ). In my table i use for this field is BBMgrID  nvarchar(50) NOT NULL

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=spilap;Initial Catalog=spiDB;User ID=sa;Password=sa123");

    protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_BBmgr values('" + TextBox1.Text+"')",con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Is your PC named **spilap**? Do you have an SQL Server instance named **spiDB** with a table **tbl_BBmgr** that has only one field **BBMgrID**? Is the **sa** password for the SQL Server instance **sa123**?

Comment: try by changing nvarchar(50) to varchar(50)

Comment: Do you have a primary key field in your table that is auto-incremented?

Comment: try with `Insert into tbl_BBmgr (BBMgrID) values('" + TextBox1.Text+"')"`

Comment: @JohnGathogo Login to sql server using spilap database is spiDB table is tbl_BBmgr... i have 5 fileds but BBmgrID is NotNull filed.all others Null fields

Comment: @SpiderX there is a conflict in your question and previous comment (question says BBMgrID is null & your comment you are telling it is not null). Which is correct?? Give sufficient details in the question, so that it is easy for others to give an answer.

Comment: @prashantht oh mybad,that is Not null field.. other than this all other fields are NULL

Comment: @SpiderX OK. so all you are trying to do is to insert value from TextBox1.Text into BBMgrID field and let other fields be null. If this is the case, solution given by 'Damith' in the comments should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert [TableName] ([ColumnName]) Values(@A)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A", TextBox1.text);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Update :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert [TableName] ([Column1],[Column2],[Column3]) Values(@A,@B,@C)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A", TextBox1.text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@B", TextBox2.text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C", TextBox3.text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Please explain what happen in this line  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A", TextBox1.text);

Comment: +1 for using parametrized query and avoiding the SQL injection.

Comment: if you want declare a value in the query line you must use @ before the name for declaration for example @a or @name you can use whatever you want after @ exactly like declaration. then when you want to show that what does @A mean you must use Parameters.AddWithValue the first value is that declared value @A the second one must be the value TextBox1.Text.

Comment: @aliboy38 In the software industry also doing like this ?( I mean commercial applications ?)

Comment: @SpiderX yes. so please mark this answer as answered question.

Comment: @SpiderX if this answer worked for you then please mark the check mark under vote situation to shows it is your answer and mark as answered question

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this:
Insert into tbl_BBmgr (BBMgrID) values('" + TextBox1.Text+"')

Comment: No, you shouldn't. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection. See `aliboy38` answer for the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If like you stated you have 5 fields in the DB table, you need to explicitly specify the column you want the value to go:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_BBmgr (BBMgrID) values('" + TextBox1.Text+"')",con);
```

**EDIT**: Now and in the future, to ensure that you are sending the right value to the respective field, its always advisable to specify the columns in your INSERT statement in the form:

```
INSERT INTO Name_Of_Table ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], ...) VALUES ([Value_For_Column1], [Value_For_Column2], [Value_For_Column3], ...)
```